# Use Equations 1 and 2 to eliminate $T$ and show the expression for $f$ is given by

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I am not quite understanding what needs to be done but I am assuming that I must combine the two equations and get rid of the variable $T$ in order to make this equation of $f$ below:

(Note:These formulas are in the regards to inclined planes)

**Equation of $f$:** 
$$f=g(m-M\sin(\theta))-(m+M)a$$

**Equation #1:** 
$$T-Mg\sin(\theta)-f=Ma$$

**Equation #2:** $$mg-T=ma$$

Here is the work I have done so far:

$$T-Mg\sin(\theta)-f-Ma=mg-T-ma$$

(I add and subtract the variables to one side where I get)

$$f=2T-g(m-M\sin(\theta))-(m+M)a$$

The only part that is confusing me is, how do I get rid of the variable $T$ in this equation?

(NOTE: I am not looking for the answer but only how to deal with this type of problem so that I may know what to do in the future if this problem comes around. Also please edit this post for the sake of the quality of the content of this stack exchange site)

I thank everyone in advance for the contribution to answering this question

Comment: Try adding Equation (2) to Equation (1) by matching the sides of the equations (i.e. $ma$ is added to $Ma$ and similarly for the *other* side).

Comment: Oh so all I do is solve for T on both equations then set them equal to each other?

Comment: That's the other way to do it. I figured since you added them together once already it'd be easier to explain it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your three equations are not linearly independent and so check your math. You should have 3 independent equations to solve for 3 variables like $T$, $f$ and $a$.

In general you solve for one variable in one equation and substitute it into the others. Like equation **#2** $T= m (g-a)$ to get

$$ f = - M g \sin\theta - (M+m) a + m g $$.

Then repeat for the next variable. In your case pluggin the above $f$ into equation **#1** returns $M a=M a$ which is not helpful and hence I stated that your equations *should be* independent to solve correctly.

Can you post a diagram in order to check your equations also?

Comment: ja72: if I understand the question correctly you use equations 2 and 3 to derive 1, so they are indeed not linearly independant.